# fixing cell padding via html in a access database

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

I currently have a code in a database that sends an email with a table
The table currently is not formatted it correctly and Im unable to apply cell padding. Any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsFL7.png)

Here is the code accompanying it

```
Function exporthtml()

Dim strline, strHTML, strMsg
Dim Cnt As String
Dim strFilt As String
Dim ACname As String
Dim filt As String
Dim strCC As String

Cnt = DCount("[PATS Action ID]", "tblPAT", "Bureau='" &    Form_frmMainPATS.cboBur.Value & "'")
ACname = DLookup("FIRSTNAME", "qryAC", "Bureau='" &   Form_frmMainPATS.txtFull.Value & "'")
strFilt = DLookup("WORKEMAIL", "qryAC", "Bureau='" &    Form_frmMainPATS.txtFull.Value & "'")
 Dim OL As Outlook.Application

 Set OL = New Outlook.Application
 Set MyItem = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)


 Report_rptCurrentPATS.Filter = "Bureau='" & Form_frmMainPATS.cboBur.Value & "'"
Report_rptCurrentPATS.FilterOn = True

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptCurrentPATS", acFormatHTML, "R:\Epi- Admin\Administrative Collaboration\Admin Review Meetings\Weekly Administrative Reports\Working Documents\Bureau Status Report Updates\TEST.html"

Open "R:\Epi-Admin\Administrative Collaboration\Admin Review   Meetings\Weekly Administrative Reports\Working Documents\Bureau Status Report Updates\TEST.html" For Input As 1
Do While Not EOF(1)
Input #1, strline
strHTML = strHTML & strline
  Loop
Close 1
If Left(OL.Version, 2) = "10" Then
MyItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
End If
MyItem.To = strFilt
MyItem.Subject = "Updated PATS Status Report as of " & Date - 1
MyItem.HTMLBody = "<BODY bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>" & "<img src='R:\Epi-Admin\Fiscal Management and Reporting Unit\Database\PS Database\logo.png' ALT='Banner'" & "<p>" & "<FONT color = '#000000'>" & "Dear " & ACname & "," & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & Form_frmMainPATS.cboBur.Value & " currently has " & Cnt & " pending personnel actions." & "</p>" & "<p>" & "Please see the report below:" & "<br/>" & "<BODY>" & "<table border= '1'>" & "<bgcolor=#ffffff; cellspacing=10; table-layout: fixed; >" & "<table header= '1' bgcolor='#fffff'>" & strHTML & "</table>" & "</br>" & "<br/>" & "</br>" & "</br>" & "<p> If you have any questions, please contact your desingated Personnel Coordinator"
```

MyItem.Display
End Function
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I believe you are reading a line from the file and placing that inside your table element, but you are never splitting that information up and putting it in data cells to apply table row and table data formatting. If I am correct, start by creating a <tr> element (Table Row) for each strLine, then you could probably use a deliminator character to separate your data, apply a <td> (Table Data) element to each "cell".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment from above, you can try to see if something like this works or gets you in the right direction (not tested):

```
Dim strCell() as string

Do While Not EOF(1)
    Input #1, strline
    strCell() = Split(strline, vbTab) 'Replace vbTab with deliminator if needed

    dim i as integer

    for i = 0 to UBound(strCell)
        strline = "<td>" & strCell(i) & "</td>"
    next

    strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>" & strline & "</tr>"
Loop
Close 1
```